# npm err code 1 when trying npm install on vuejs project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, node-gyp

Just downloaded [VueJS Material Dashboard (with Laravel)](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vue-material-dashboard-laravel), but when I tried `npm install` on this VueJS template it shows err 1. It mentioned error related to gyp and python39. Even when I use node.js command prompt as administrator, it still showing error.

```html
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Technolife\xampp\htdocs\spk-or-as-main\node_modules\fibers
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.9.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Technolife\\xampp\\htdocs\\spk-or-as-main\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Technolife\xampp\htdocs\spk-or-as-main\node_modules\fibers
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.9.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-gyp exited with code: 1
npm ERR! Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
npm ERR! would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
npm ERR! build environment--
npm ERR! Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
npm ERR! Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
npm ERR! RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
npm ERR! Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
npm ERR! 'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\noxer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-10T08_02_45_175Z-debug.log
```

Here's the package.json on VueJS Material Dashboard project:

```html
{
  "name": "vue-material-dashboard-pro",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "dev": "npm run serve",
    "deploy": "npm run build && cd docs && npm run build && cd .. && sudo gh-pages -d dist",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm run dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "4.4.0",
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "18.5.0",
    "acorn-dynamic-import": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "chartist": "0.11.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "4.2.8",
    "fuse.js": "3.6.1",
    "google-maps": "4.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jsona": "^1.6.0",
    "jvectormap-next": "3.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nouislider": "14.1.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.0",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "sweetalert2": "9.10.0",
    "vee-validate": "3.2.5",
    "vue": "2.6.11",
    "vue-authenticate": "^1.4.1",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-clickaway": "2.2.2",
    "vue-color": "^2.7.1",
    "vue-github-buttons": "3.1.0",
    "vue-material": "^1.0.0-beta-11",
    "vue-router": "3.1.6",
    "vue-social-sharing": "2.4.7",
    "vue2-transitions": "0.3.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "6.2.2",
    "fibers": "4.0.2",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "node-sass": "4.13.1",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "sass": "1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.11"
  }
}
```

So, what's wrong with that? I tried find similar problem but it was obsolete, I hope you can give latest soluition for this `npm install` error code 1.

Comment: Could you provide output of `npm version` ?

Comment: Okay, my npm version is 7.23.0

Comment: And version of Node.js?

Comment: My Node.js version is 16.9.0

Comment: I recently have problem with 16 version of Node.js, could you downgrade it to 14?

Comment: Before downgrade, remove node_modules and package.look.json

Comment: Just downgraded my NodeJS to version 14 LTS, delete package.lock.json and node_modules (but this folder not present on my project), and assured that additional tools for node.js installed, it still showing same error as just I explained.

Comment: First of all make sure you are in project directory where package.json is located and run this: `npm cache clean --force && rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`

Comment: If not working, try to create new vue project and check for error.

Comment: Probably the Vue Material Dashboard folder project is corrupted or obsolete, because when I created new Vue project, it runs perfectly to development server without issues. Any possible fix for those broken downloaded Vue project?

Comment: Wait, I try run npm install via bash instead cmd. Let's see if it's work. UPDATE: It's still same af. I thought there something wrong on package.json

Comment: But I suspect, fibers dependency creates trouble on this project.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it in 3 steps

1. Install python 2.7 from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716   -
   `Windows x86-64 MSI installer`
2. Add Python Path to `environment variables`, in my case it was `C:\Python27`
3. Run `npm cache clean --force && rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install` in **vue-material-dashboard** folder.